# How to add keyboard support on facebook litho

Tags: android, litho

I am trying to use facebook litho to build the android app for TV.

We need to support keyboard events(up/down/left/right) to control the navigation.

I can intercept keyboard events by onKeyDown in the activity, but I don't know how to update the component's status from activity.

Answer (score 0):

### Overview

I have solved a similar problem, which is to re-render the top-level Litho component when an external action occurs by doing the following:

1. storing a reference to the `LithoView` created in my Activities `onCreate` method
2. define some kind of object to track the state across renders, this *must* contain any state needed to render your component tree. this will be a `@Prop` on your top-level component
3. create an initial state in `onCreate` and derive my initial component from this
4. when I receive a callback, compute the new state object and create a new `Component` instance from this
5. call `LithoView#setComponent(Component)` with that instance

This is essentially an implementation of the MVI approach as explained here for [Android with Mosby](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby3-mvi-1), though the example shown is highly simplified.

### Example:

Activity:

```
public class CounterActivity extends Activity {
    private LithoView lithoView; // 1: keeps the same LithoView instance for the entirety of the Activity
    private ComponentContext c;
    private State currentState; // 2: remembers the current State

    static class State {
        private int counter;

        State(int count) {
            this.counter = count;
        }

        public int getCounter() {
            return counter;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        c = new ComponentContext(this);
        // 3: create the initial UI state (note: you probably need to use savedInstanceState or some other external state here)
        setState(getInitialApplicationState());
    }

    // 4: A silly example of an Activity-level callback to drive state updates
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setState(new State(currentState.getCounter() + 1));
    }

    // This will store the new state in the Activity and update the component accordingly
    private void setState(State newState) {
        currentState = newState;
        updateView(newState);
    }

    // There is a 1:1 mapping between State and UI
    private Component componentForState(State state) {
        return CounterComponent.create(c).state(state).build();
    }

    // 5: set the Component on the LithoView for the current state
    private void updateView(State currentState) {
        Component contentComponent = componentForState(currentState);
        if (lithoView == null) {
            lithoView = LithoView.create(this, contentComponent);
            setContentView(lithoView);
        } else {
            lithoView.setComponent(contentComponent);
        }
    }

    private State getInitialApplicationState() {
        return new State(0);
    }
}
```

Spec:

```
@LayoutSpec
public class CounterComponentSpec {
    @OnCreateLayout
    static ComponentLayout onCreateLayout(
            ComponentContext c,
            @Prop CounterActivity.State state) {
        return Text.create(c)
                .text("Count: " + state.getCounter())
                .textSizeSp(44f)
                .buildWithLayout();
    }
}
```